# chartjs in react useEffect keeps on creating new charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have this extremely odd issue.. every single time I try and use a `chartjs` object, it keeps on creating itself on a  new object (new id). The initial load never works, and I have to refresh. Everytime I switch from unmounting this component to mounting, when I console.log the chart instance it's always incrementing in `id`. I'm confused as what's going wrong here.

here is a basic snipped of my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartContainer && chartContainer.current) {
            const newChartInstance = new Chartjs(chartContainer.current!, chartConfig);
            removeData(newChartInstance);
            if (newChartInstance) {
                setIsClear(true);
                setChartInstance(newChartInstance);
                return () => {
                    removeData(newChartInstance);
                    newChartInstance.destroy();
                    if (chartInstance) chartInstance.destroy();
                }
            }
    };
  }, [chartContainer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartInstance && delay) {
        const intervalUpdate = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("updating");
            console.log(chartInstance);
            chartInstance.update(); 
        }, delay);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalUpdate);
    }
  }, [chartInstance, delay])

  return (
    <div className={styles.chartContainer}>
      <canvas ref={chartContainer} height={"140"}/>
    </div>
  );
```

On the initial load a chart is created, and I'm adding data to it. But I believe 2nd one gets created and that's holding no data & is what is being display on the canvas. I know there's two somehow because because when I log I get an `id` of `1`, instead of `0`.

When I `console.log()` chart instance, on the very first initial load is always:

```
Chart {id: 1, ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, canvas: canvas.chartjs-render-monitor, config: {…}, width: 1024, …}
```

Which I believe is why my chart is empty. When I refresh it goes back to:

```
Chart {id: 0, ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, canvas: canvas.chartjs-render-monitor, config: {…}, width: 1024, …}
```

which properly displays the data.

Comment: Could you please add your return jsx part also